# Check invalid date in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, amazon-redshift

I am dealing with Amazon Redshift.

I have a date column in `YYYYMMDD` format. I need to write a query to check invalid dates:

1. Each month should have appropriate days, eg: if June has date part as 31, then return the column.
2. When date has 29 Feb on a non-leap year then return the column

Comment: You can't store an invalid date in a `date` column

Comment: except if you use mysql :)

Comment: What is the Data Type of that column?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "a date column in YYYYMMDD" format - in redshift date columns have a DATE, TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMPTZ datatype that has no format; internally it is a numerical representation of a point in time and your query tool or front end app formats it accordingly to the desired culture/region in which it's being displayed, or based on the user's expressed language, etc

What you have is a string or integer column that contains some numbers that look like a date, if one understands that the first 4 digits represent the year.. and so on

And now you're asking how to ensure this "thing that looks like it might represent a date" is a valid date?

Use a proper DATE/TIME/TIMESTAMPTZ data type on the column. You'll be able to do math with it then too, there wont be any invalid values, it can do timezone based operations too, it will sort correctly no matter what culture, and noone will ever look at "20121211" and think it's the "20th December 1211". Or maybe it's 11th December 2012. Or maybe it's 12th Nov 2012. Or...